# Show Users who are in 10 KM radius from User current location Android

Tags: android, gps, location, appserver

I have a requirement where I want to get the user's current location and based on the user's current location I want to get other user's information from app server and want to show them in a list. Users should be within 5 or 10 km radius.
I fetched users data from server showing it in the app but I want to show within that particular radius. **Any help is appreciable**.

Comment: Basically you need to calculate distance between 2 points of google map. accordingly you can set logic weather current location is inside or outside the calculated radius.

Comment: OR you can use https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence there.

Comment: i want to show the data in recycler view not on map

Comment: "Users should be within 5 or 10 km radius." that logic should be implemented on server side.Then where are you stuck!

Comment: actually i didn't understand how to compare the current location with the locations stored in database (by using latitude and longitude or by location name)  and how to check latitude and longitudes radius.

Comment: Yo need to send your device location (lat,long) to server. Inside that API on server side that logic should be implemented (100 m range). In the response of that API you will get #list of users (devices) what ever in side 100m.Then display that list inside recycler view. Make sense!

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [**Geofences**](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html), Please follow the below steps you definitely get the result as you want.

Let's see how it's work.

*Geofencing combines awareness of the user's current location with awareness of the user's proximity to locations that may be of interest. To mark a location of interest, you specify its latitude and longitude. To adjust the proximity for the location, you add a radius. **The latitude, longitude, and radius define a geofence, creating a circular area, or fence, around the location of interest**.*

**You can have multiple active geofences, with a limit of 100 per device user.**

[image]

Now, let's see how we use it in our application,

#### Set up for Geofence Monitoring

The first step in requesting geofence monitoring is to request the necessary permission. To use geofencing, your app must request [ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION). To request this permission, add the following element as a child element of the [`<manifest>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) element in your app manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

If you want to use an [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) to listen for geofence transitions, add an element specifying the service name. This element must be a child of the [`<application>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html) element:

```
<application
   android:allowBackup="true">
   ...
   <service android:name=".GeofenceTransitionsIntentService"/>
<application/>
```

To access the location APIs, you need to create an instance of the Geofencing client. To learn how to connect your client:

```
private GeofencingClient mGeofencingClient;

// ...

mGeofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);
```

#### Create and Add Geofences

> **Note:** On single-user devices, there is a limit of 100 geofences per
>   app. For multi-user devices, the limit is 100 geofences per app per
>   device user.

- Create geofence objects

First, use [Geofence.Builder](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.Builder) to create a geofence, setting the desired radius, duration, and transition types for the geofence. For example, to populate a list object named mGeofenceList:

```
 mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
    // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
    // geofence.
    .setRequestId(entry.getKey())

    .setCircularRegion(
            entry.getValue().latitude,
            entry.getValue().longitude,
            Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
    )
    .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
    .build());
```

#### Specify geofences and initial triggers

The following snippet uses the [GeofencingRequest](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingRequest) class and its nested [GeofencingRequestBuilder](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingRequest.Builder) class to specify the geofences to monitor and to set how related geofence events are triggered:

```
private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}
```

#### Define an Intent for geofence transitions

The [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) sent from Location Services can trigger various actions in your app, but you should not have it start an activity or fragment, because components should only become visible in response to a user action. In many cases, an [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) is a good way to handle the intent. An [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) can post a notification, do long-running background work, send intents to other services, or send a broadcast intent. The following snippet shows how to define a [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) that starts an [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ...

    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
        // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
        if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
            return mGeofencePendingIntent;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
        // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when
        // calling addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
        mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.
                FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
```

#### Add geofences

To add geofences, use the [GeofencingClient.addGeofences()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingClient#addGeofences(com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) method. Provide the [GeofencingRequest](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingRequest) object, and the [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html). The following snippet demonstrates processing the results:

```
mGeofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(), getGeofencePendingIntent())
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                // Geofences added
                // ...
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                // Failed to add geofences
                // ...
            }
        });
```

#### Handle Geofence Transitions

> **Note:** On Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher, if an app is running in the background while monitoring a geofence, then the device
>   responds to geofencing events every couple of minutes. To learn how to
>   adapt your app to these response limits, see Background Location
>   Limits.

```
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {
    // ...
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                    geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
            return;
        }

        // Get the transition type.
        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

            // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger
            // multiple geofences.
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            // Get the transition details as a String.
            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
                    this,
                    geofenceTransition,
                    triggeringGeofences
            );

            // Send notification and log the transition details.
            sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);
            Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
        } else {
            // Log the error.
            Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type,
                    geofenceTransition));
        }
    }
```

#### Stop Geofence Monitoring

```
mGeofencingClient.removeGeofences(getGeofencePendingIntent())
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                // Geofences removed
                // ...
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                // Failed to remove geofences
                // ...
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should implement logic on server based on the latitude and longitude and return the data